# $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\ni a<b<{1\over a}$ and $x=(a+{1\over a})-(b+{1\over b})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b\in\mathbb{R}\ni a,b>0, a<b<{1\over a}$ and $$x=(a+{1\over a})-(b+{1\over b})$$

Then $a) x>0$

b) $x<0$

$c) x=0$

d) no such conclusion can be drawn  about $x$

just confirm me that answer is $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a<\frac{1}{a}$ so $a<-1$ or $0<a<1$. In the first case $y=t+\frac 1t$ is strictly increasing  but in the second case it is strictly decreasing,because $y'=1-\frac{1}{t^2}$

Given that $a>0$ then we should have $0<a<1$, and therefore $y=t+\frac 1t$ is decreasing so $a<b \to (a+\frac{1}{a})>(b+\frac{1}{b}) \to (a+\frac{1}{a})-(b+\frac{1}{b})>0 $

Comment: $a,b>0$ I am sorry......

Comment: @Sade I updated my answer, please update the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $a < 1$, because $a<\frac1a$. If $a < b < \frac 1 a$, then also $a < \frac 1 b < \frac 1 a$, so without loss of generality $b \leq 1$ and we have
$$x = (a+\frac1a) - (b + \frac1b) = a-b + \frac1a-\frac1b =a-b - \frac{a-b}{ab} =\\= \frac{ab(a-b) - (a-b)}{ab} = \frac{(a-b)(ab-1)}{ab} = \frac{(b-a)(1-ab)}{ab}$$
Now $b-a > 0$, $ab>0$, and also $1-ab > 1-b \geq 0$, so in the end
$$x = \frac{(b-a)(1-ab)}{ab} > 0$$